# Ajax Form: Wrong value sent back

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to figure out why this form always always returns "Error" when JavaScript is activated, but works like it should when JavaScript is deactivated.
It has something to do with with `echo "success"` and `echo "error"`, but I really can't find out whats wrong. I tried to echo `1` or `2`, `true` or `false` - it never works. Why?

My jQuery code:

```
$("form").submit(function () {

        var name     = $( "input[name=name]" ),
            mail     = $( "input[name=email]" ),
            message  = $( "textarea[name=message]" );

        var data = "name=" + name.val() + "&mail=" + mail.val() + "&message="  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());

        $.ajax({
            url: "my_form.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
                success: function ( data ) {
                    if ( data == "success" ) {
                        alert( "Everyhting is good." );
                    } else {
                        alert( "Error" );
                    }
                }
        });

        return false;
})
```

And the PHP part:

```
$name    = $_POST["name"];
$email   = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

function checkEmail( $e ) {

    $isValid = true;

    if ( strlen( $e ) === 0 ) {
        $isValid = false;
    }

    if ( !preg_match( "/^((?:(?:(?:\w[\.\-\+]?)*)\w)+)\@((?:(?:(?:\w[\.\-\+]?){0,62})\w)+)\.(\w{2,6})$/", $e ) ) {
        $isValid = false;
    }

    if ( $isValid == true ) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}

checkEmail( $email );
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like you using the variable `data` twice? Once for the name, value pairs and once for the success. Try changing the first data variable to be called toSend or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling email `mail` in the data string and expecting `$_POST['email']` in php.

```
var data = "name=" + name.val() + "&mail=" + mail.val() + "&message="  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());
```

change `mail` in the line above to email like below.

```
var data = "name=" + name.val() + "&email=" + mail.val() + "&message="  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I simply did not see this although I checked it about 100 times ;-)